# Поворот img не выходя за пределы div

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, transform

Имеется div в нем img при нажатии на картинку поворачиваю на 90 град (transform:rotate). Но проблема в том, что img начинает выходить за div перекрывая вышестоящие элементы.
overflow:hidden не решение.

```js
$('.imgPrevAuto').on('click', function() {
  deg += 90;
  $('.imgPrevAuto').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
  .imgPrevAuto {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 column text-center" id="imgShow" style="height: 1368px;">
    <img src="path" class="imgPrevAuto">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: {Хотелось бы так]

Comment: А какого поведения вы ожидали? Приложите код, который будет воспроизводить проблему. Опишите, что бы вы хотели получить в итоге.

Comment: transform не меняет расположения (размеры и реальный поворот) картинки. Поэтому нужно дополнительно считать ширины картинки и высоту дива и добавить коэффициент разницы в scale()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var angle = 90;
$('div').click(function(){
  var blockHeight = $(this).height(),
      img = $(this).children('img');
      
  img.css('transform','rotate('+angle+'deg)');
  angle%180 ? img.addClass('side'):img.removeClass('side');
  
  angle +=90;
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
img{
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100px;
  width:auto;
}
img.side{
  width:100px;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://coubsecure-s.akamaihd.net/get/b28/p/coub/simple/cw_timeline_pic/04b5e5624e5/a67f00fb81c169ee1a6a8/med_1429990100_image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант -  крутить див с картинкой , а не картинку внутри дива.
Или присваивать высоте дива значение ширины картинки при повороте.